# Кумулятивное суммирование с условием

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame

```
myData ={'A':[1,3,-10,4,5,6,2],
     'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сделать в новой колонке кумулятивное суммирование по колонке 'A' но с условием, что если результат положительный, то ставим 0, если результат <0, то начинаем кумулятивное суммирование по колонке 'A'.
Для колонки 'B' нужно начинать кумулятивное суммирование, если в колонке 'A-' значение <0
Реализовал это обычными циклами, только начинаю осваивать pandas и хотелось бы использовать инструменты из этого пакета

[image: Результат:]

Comment: можете привести пример данных, в котором будут две точки начала суммирования?

Comment: похоже без циклов все равно не обойтись, ведь следующая точка точка начала суммирования известна только после предыдущего прохода.

Comment: @strawdog он же там есть

Comment: Следующая точка  начала суммирования будет на следующем отрицательном значении. myData ={'A':[1,3,-10,4,5,6,2, -7,5],
     'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,8,1]} Первая точка на -10, вторая на -7

Comment: Циклы на больших размерах данных, более 500К строк долго обрабатываются.

Comment: Юрий, тут скорее нужно знать точку окончания суммирования. с точками начала суммирования проблем как раз нет.

Comment: В первой колонке с результатами 'A-' должны быть только отрицательные значения. Как только получаем +, ставим ноль и останавливаем суммирование. Если поможет могу привести мой код с циклами.

Comment: Юрий. вам splash об этом и написал - сначала нужно вычислить точку останова (там, где мы получаем "+"). Векторизированным функциями pandas это маловероятно сделать. Надо думать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@strawdog огромное спасибо!
Ваши ответы и ссылка [вот этот кейс](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390300/how-to-reset-cumsum-after-change-in-sign-of-values) позволили найти верное решение.
В первой части Вашего ответа корректно считалась кумулятивная сумма, когда в колонке условий есть смена знака, после Update корректно стало работать, когда нет смены знака.

Вот немного измененный код, который дает нужные значения:

```
import pandas as pd
myData ={'A':[1,3,-10,4,5,6,2,-7,5],
         'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,1,2]}

myData1 ={'A':[1,3,-20,4,5,6,2,-7,5],
          'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,1,2]}

def myfunc(myData: dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
    df['temp']=df.groupby(df['A'].lt(0).astype(int).cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['temp'] > 0, 'temp'] = 0
    df['A-']=df.groupby(df['temp'].lt(0).astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['A-'] > 0, 'A-'] = 0
    df.drop(['temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df['BA-']=df.groupby(df['A-'].lt(0).astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum())['B'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['A-'] == 0, 'BA-'] = 0

print(myfunc(myData))

#     A  B  A-  BA-
# 0   1  2   0    0
# 1   3  1   0    0
# 2 -10  4 -10    4
# 3   4  2  -6    6
# 4   5  5  -1   11
# 5   6  3   0    0
# 6   2  6   0    0
# 7  -7  1  -7    1
# 8   5  2  -2    3

print(myfunc(myData1))

#     A  B  A-  BA-
# 0   1  2   0    0
# 1   3  1   0    0
# 2 -20  4 -20    4
# 3   4  2 -16    6
# 4   5  5 -11   11
# 5   6  3  -5   14
# 6   2  6  -3   20
# 7  -7  1 -10   21
# 8   5  2  -5   23
```

Отказ от циклов и переход на использование функционала Pandas позволило очень существенно сократить время выполнения программы. Для 2,5 млн записей скорость увеличилась в 100 раз!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот, по мотивам [этого кейса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390300/how-to-reset-cumsum-after-change-in-sign-of-values) получается такой колхоз:

```
import pandas as pd
myData ={'A':[1,3,-10,4,5,6,2,-7,5],
     'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)

#    A  B
#0   1  2
#1   3  1
#2 -10  4
#3   4  2
#4   5  5
#5   6  3
#6   2  6
#7  -7  1
#8   5  2
```

Затем:

```
df['A-']=df.groupby(df['A'].lt(0).astype(int).cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
df.loc[df['A-'] > 0, 'A-'] = 0
df['BA-']=df.groupby(df['A-'].lt(0).astype(int))['B'].cumsum()
df.loc[df['A-'] == 0, 'BA-'] = 0
```

Что даёт в результате:

```
    A  B  A-  BA-
0   1  2   0    0
1   3  1   0    0
2 -10  4 -10    4
3   4  2  -6    6
4   5  5  -1   11
5   6  3   0    0
6   2  6   0    0
7  -7  1  -7   12
8   5  2  -2   14
```

То есть, кумулятивная сумма происходит только с теми значениями, которые вам нужны, но она не ресетится, а продолжает аккумулироваться с каждой очередной серией.

**UPDATE**

Появилось справедливое замечание, что если кумулятивная сумма в первой колонке после точки начала суммирования до следующего отрицательного числа не набежит в "плюс", то приведенное выше решение не будет работать. Поэтому появилась такая адаптация (код особо не оптимизировал, он и так трудночитаем):

```
import pandas as pd
myData ={'A':[1,3,-10,4,5,6,2,-7,5],
     'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,1,2]}

myData1 ={'A':[1,3,-20,4,5,6,2,-7,5],
     'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6,1,2]}

def myfunc(myData: dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
    df['temp']=df.groupby(df['A'].lt(0).astype(int).cumsum())['A'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['temp'] > 0, 'temp'] = 0
    df['A-']=df.groupby(df['temp'].lt(0).astype(int))['A'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['A-'] > 0, 'A-'] = 0
    df.drop(['temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df['BA-']=df.groupby(df['A-'].lt(0).astype(int))['B'].cumsum()
    df.loc[df['A-'] == 0, 'BA-'] = 0
    return df

print(myfunc(myData))

#     A  B  A-  BA-
# 0   1  2   0    0
# 1   3  1   0    0
# 2 -10  4 -10    4
# 3   4  2  -6    6
# 4   5  5  -1   11
# 5   6  3   0    0
# 6   2  6   0    0
# 7  -7  1  -8   12
# 8   5  2  -3   14

print(myfunc(myData1))

#     A  B  A-  BA-
# 0   1  2   0    0
# 1   3  1   0    0
# 2 -20  4 -20    4
# 3   4  2 -16    6
# 4   5  5 -11   11
# 5   6  3  -5   14
# 6   2  6  -3   20
# 7  -7  1 -10   21
# 8   5  2  -5   23
```

Comment: боюсь, если между -10 и -7 сумма не набежит в плюс, схема не сработает, если я ее правильно понял

Comment: Спасибо большое! Колонка 'B' и 'BA-' расчитываются корректно. Это уже часть задачи решило! А вот ситуация, которую описал splash, когда  между -10 и -7 сумма не набежит в плюс, схема действительно не работает. Вот на этом например myData ={'A':[1,3,-20,4,5,6,2, -7,5], 'B':[2,1,4,2,5,3,6, 8, 1]}. Просто увеличив первый минус в два раза.

Comment: @splash58 не было времени основательно подумать, единственное, что пришло в голову - это промежуточная группировка.

Comment: надо, наверное, делать цикл - смотрим сумму, берем когда она становится неправильной, делаем с этого места слайс и повторяем процесс. И так до конца столбца А. Мне вот так видится

Comment: @splash58, ну, как я понял, автор уже и так решил задачу с помощью циклов. хотелось найти как раз пандовское решение.